# Application use on website

Tags: c#, web-development, javascript, web-applications, ajax

Is there a good way to run a C# application on clientside in lieu of JavaScript? I have done some front end work with JavaScript and backend C# for web developing at an old job, but I am interested in hosting a website myself soon. I have a C# application I would like to be open source, but before people care to download I'd like them to be able to use it. At its basic level it's a simple text editor, but there's much more to it in the nitty gritty. I could write it in JavaScript, but it would require me to keep documentation and up to date changes on JavaScript and C# in that case.

I was thinking of creating an AJAX panel and somehow loading my winform application into a frame, but I don't know how or what words to google because I've never done it before except AJAX.

Comment: If you open source the project, maybe you can rely on the JavaScript expertise of others and learn something in the process?

Comment: I'm essentially trying to accomplish that...

Comment: Life would be so much easier if everyone could use C# instead of Javascript in web browsers. *I'm talking white unicorns with naked woman riding them and throwing flower petals at your feet kind of better life.*

Comment: Would you not be able to preview your text editor in Silverlight? It's a dying plugin, but I think lots of people still have it from the point in time when Netflix used it, and it's a pretty fast/trusted install.

Comment: Maybe adapting [mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) for [nacl](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client)? But that probably may need months of work....

Answer (score 2):

An ASP.NET WebForms application will be your best bet in the short term.

Your skills at WinForms will be largely transferable, however you'll need to make yourself familiar with where you're WinForm is relying on persisted state objects. These pieces of data that need to be persisted throughout the lifetime of the application, that are not part of server-side controls themselves, will need to be manually persisted via either the [ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) or [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx) state.

WebForms is not an ideal technology for the stateless web, but it was designed for developers that are familiar with Winform development.

Diving into full-blown stateless MVC has a considerable learning curve if you aren't used to web development.

Answer (score 0):

What capabilities do you have in C# that you feel are missing from Javascript?  C# will run in a browser, but it will require your users to grant permission for a plugin.  You don't want that.

Learn and use Javascript.  Failing that, you can try writing an [XBAP application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAML_Browser_Applications).

Comment: "What capabilities do you have in C# that you feel are missing from Javascript?" – If I understood the question correctly, the most important capability missing from JavaScript is the application itself, which already exists and is already written in C#. The OP wants his potential users to be able to try out his *desktop* app on the web before downloading it.

Comment: Correct, Jörg W Mittag.

Comment: Normally, one would *install* C# applications.  Your user downloads and installs a trial version.  If you want something that runs in a web browser and on a desktop, you would typically use HTML5/CSS3/Javascript for that.

Comment: They would install the application once they download it. But you may be right. It may be more beneficial for me to rewrite in JavaScript so that it can be both hosted on web, and if I can find a useful way, usable as desktop application. I've never attempted creating JavaScript that doesn't run in a web browser. I have research to do on how that works.

Comment: Why don't you just write a mockup of your application in a browser, or make some screenshot walkthroughs?  It doesn't have to be a full-featured mockup (you're not going to get that in a browser sandbox anyway), and a walkthrough will teach people how the application works.

Comment: Then too, if your original application had used a XAML framework, there would be a clear path to making it available on the web. Winforms makes that a bit harder.

Comment: And if you already have the application, if security considerations permit, you might be able to install it via ClickOnce: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce